# Calculating the Roots of Sine

Tags: trigonometry, roots

Aside from the obvious knowledge that the roots of $\sin x$ are all integer multiples of $\pi$, is there a formal, algebraic method to calculate the roots of trigonometric functions similar to the quadratic equation?

(e.g. roots of $\sin^2(ax) + \sin(bx) + c$ or some other non-trivial form)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While trigonometric identities exist for multiples of an angle, perhaps the best-known being:

$$
\begin{align}
\sin 2x &= 2\sin x \cos x\\
\cos 2x &= \cos^2 x - \sin^2{x} =2\cos^2 x - 1 = 1 - 2 \sin^2x\\
\sin 3x &= 3\sin x - 4 \sin^3 x\\
\cos 3x &= 4\cos^3 x - 3\cos x
\end{align}
$$

there is no such general formula, and indeed no way to solve such equations, unless the trigonometric arguments are the same and therefore the expression can be factored.

Comment: using those identities, is there a simpler root for something like $\cos ax + \cos bx$ ?

Comment: You would have to use the individual cosine identities for _a_ and _b_ to expand the expressions and then solve. For example, try using the identities I just gave to solve $\cos 3x - 2\cos 2x = 0$.

Comment: I follow your expansion to $4\cos^3 x - 3 \cos x - 4 \cos^2 x =2 $ but without resorting to the trivial integer multiple of $(n+\(1/2) ) \pi $, I'm not with you.

Comment: @JasonNichols for $\cos(ax)+\cos(bx)=0$ use sum to product identities. But in general there is no method for solving a generic $f(x)=0$ other than numerical approximation.

Comment: @JasonNichols Try using the [cubic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots).

Comment: @JasonNichols, for $\cos ax + \cos bx$ you could use the identity $$\cos ax + \cos bx = 2 \cos\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\,x\right) \cos\left(\frac{a-b}{2}\,x\right)$$ then find the zeros of each cosine in the product.